# getFromLocationName error, Service not available. Have been working, stopped

Tags: android, geolocation

In my app I am using the getFromLocationName, and it has been working in the app until recently, now all of a sudden I am getting is "Service not available".

The exception says: Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)

This is the code I am using:

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
 List<Address> address = null;
 try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(navAddr,5);
 } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

To be honest I do not know if has stopped working after I have switched to release build.

I hope someone can point me to what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I have the excact same problem. I have two apps there has been working perfectly for a while, but stopped working today. What is weird is that in three phones it's not working (2.2, 4.0 and 4.1) but in android 2.1 there's no problem.

There seems to be a problem with the Google Maps Geocoder service, and not our use of the service.

Edit:
I just found out that you just have to restart your phone.

Comment: I've got similar case: works on Nexus One with 2.3.6, but not on my two 4.0 devices.

Comment: This happened to all my test devices as well. I'm guessing it has to do with the Google Place Services update that was silently rolled out to support the new Maps API (among other things) **This is terrible!** Google better find a way to fix this without a restart or all our apps will appear broken!