# Android Geocoder not working on ICS: how to resolve without reboot?

Tags: android, geolocation

Is it possibile to resolve the "Service not available" problem of the Geocoder on ICS without rebooting the device?
The problem is described here: [getFromLocationName error, Service not available. Have been working, stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711892/getfromlocationname-error-service-not-available-have-been-working-stopped)
I'm going crazy...

This is the code I am using:

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
 List<Address> address = null;
 try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(navAddr,5);
 } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: can you share some code to call the service ?

Comment: @AbdulWahab here it is, the standard code for calling Geocoder

Comment: I have implemented a web service call where I found service not available exception, thus my required geo coder feature is working.

Comment: @AbdulWahab so I should resolve this issue in that way? Can you post some code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear, I am not using Stackoverflow as frequently, Have you done with your logic ? or should I try to code like I done b4. ?